# $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^3 +x+1\rangle$ are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2 +x+1\rangle$ are isomorphic or not?

I guess these are isomorphic as they are isomorphic to the field of complex number. But how can I answer about the following question:

$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^3 +x+1\rangle$ are isomorphic?

Comment: If they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, then they are isomorphic to each other; such is the nature of isomorphisms.

Comment: @Théophile: I have edited the question.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the title and the question body, as well as the question and itself; are you asking about $x^3+x+1$ or $x^2+x+1$? I assume the latter, but could you edit to fix this? (And the two questions do not belong together; if you mean to ask both, it'd be better to write two questions)

Comment: @math : you could also accept these answers : [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426989), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228166),  [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479876),  [(4)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749116),  [(5)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749946),  [(6)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752194),  [(7)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752848),  [(8)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772164),  [(9)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776120). Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rings $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2 +x+1\rangle$ are isomorphic, because they're both isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ (easy proof).

$\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^3 +x+1\rangle$ are $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, the former has dimension $2$ and the latter has dimension $3$. So they aren't certainly isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

As far as only the ring structure is concerned, they're not isomorphic because one is a field and the other one isn't.

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not isomorphic.

Pure Algebra tells us that the dimension of each is equal to the degree of the monic polynomial mentioned in its definition.

Let $\alpha$ be the real root of $X^3+X+1$, so that this polynomial factors as $(X-\alpha)(X^2+\alpha X+\alpha^2+1)$, where the second, quadratic, factor has negative discriminant. Call one its (complex) roots $\beta$. Then we map
\begin{align}
\Bbb R[X]&\>\longrightarrow\>\Bbb C\oplus\Bbb R\\
f(X)&\>\mapsto\>\bigl(f(\beta),\,f(\alpha)\bigr)\>.
\end{align}
You see that the only way a polynomial $f$ can go to zero is if $f(\beta)=f(\alpha)=0$, in other words if and only if $(X^3+X+1)\big|f(X)$, so that the kernel of our map is $(X^3+X+1)$. This shows that we’ve established an isomorphism between $\Bbb C\oplus\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R[X]/(X^3+X+1)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra implies that every finite field extension of $\mathbb R$ has degree at most $2$ and so is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

This settles the isomorphism class for $\mathbb R[x]/(f(x))$ when $f$ is irreducible of degree at most $2$.

There are no other irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb R$. In particular, a cubic polynomial is never irreducible and so the quotient ring in this case then:

- $\mathbb R \times \mathbb C$, if the cubic has exactly one real root. This is the case for $x^3 +x+1$.
- $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, if the cubic has three distinct real roots.
- $\mathbb R \times A$, if the cubic has three real roots, one being a double root. Here $A = \mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$.

A similar analysis applies to higher degree polynomials.